# Using WMI objects in VB script to decide which programs to run

Tags: vbscript, wmic

I have a vbscript that will find the OS, Service pack and OS Architecture but when i try to use the object in a If then statement its not defined, I tried to declare it but that didn't work.  What i am trying to complete is create a script that will define the OS, Service pack and whether the system is x86 or x64 and the execute a program that will install the updates specific for that system but I'm stuck.

```
Set dtmConvertedDate = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
    Wscript.Echo "Version: " & objOperatingSystem.Version
    Wscript.Echo "Service Pack: " & objOperatingSystem.CSDVersion
    Wscript.Echo "CPU Bit: " & objOperatingSystem.OSArchitecture
Next
```

Comment: Where is the `if` statement? What is the result in the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are not storing those variables you are echoing with "wscript.echo"..

You could use this example (or make a case statement):

```
Set dtmConvertedDate = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
   osVersion      = objOperatingSystem.Version
   osCSDVersion   = objOperatingSystem.CSDVersion
   osArchitecture = objOperatingSystem.OSArchitecture
Next

Wscript.Echo "Version: "  & osVersion
Wscript.Echo "Service Pack: " & osCSDVersion
Wscript.Echo "CPU Bit: " & osArchitecture


If InStr(LCase(osArchitecture), "64-bit") Then
    wscript.echo "64-bit"
    ' .... Do stuff here ....
Else
    wscript.echo "not 64-bit"
    ' .... Do stuff here ....
End If
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. that's what I was trying to do. Save the output from the "Wscript.echo" to a variable so I could use the information as part of the If then else statement. Any additional help is appreciated. As you can tell, I am new in VB scripting.

Comment: I have done that for you in this script. I have saved the values as "osVersion" "osCSDVersion" and "osArchitecture"